# Автоматизация скачивания приложений

Tags: java, android, test-automation

Дана задача написать некое приложение (или тест или скрипт не знаю как правильнее) в котором вводим название любого приложения из `Google Play Market`, к примеру `WhatsApp` и нажимаем кнопку.

Программа переходит в `Google Play Marke`t, в поиске пишет название того приложения, которое мы ему задали изначально, находит его и скачивает на устройство.

Как это можно реализовать? Что-то вроде бота вместо человека (будто человек ввел в поиске название приложения нашел и скачал)

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего сообщения я предположил, что вы хотите автоматизировать установку приложений на телефоне\планшете под управлением ОС Android.

Для этого существует несколько различных фреймворков, некоторые более подробно описаны здесь: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing

Стандартом индустрии можно считать Appium (http://appium.io/)

Пример скрипта, который делает то, что вам нужно здесь: https://github.com/Simon-Kaz/AppiumSampleTests/blob/master/src/test/java/installAppFromGooglePlaystore.java

Еще подробнее: https://medium.com/@SimonKaz/appium-test-example-download-app-from-google-play-store-6ed932663f09